# Duplicating MySql Column Values VS Foreign Key - Best Practice

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We are currently in the process of developing our own e-commerce solution, as part of our research we have been examining the ZenCart Database Schema and found that data is quite frequently duplicated between various tables where it would seem that perhaps a Foreign Key would have been sufficient to link the two or more tables in question, for example:

Given that there is table "Products" that has the following columns

PRODUCT_ID
PRODUCT_NAME
PRODUCT_PRICE
PRODUCT_SKU

Then if there is a Sales_Item "Table" Then of course a product (and all its constituent columns)may be referenced by simply doing something like:

SALES_ITEM_ID
Products_PRODUCT_ID  //This is the foreign key that relates a specific product to a sale item.
SALE_TIME
REST_OF_SALE_SPECIFIC_DATA......

However instead it seems that the Sales table COPIES many of the field values defined in the Products table so it infact looks as follows:

SALES_ITEM_ID
PRODUCT_ID
PRODUCT_NAME
PRODUCT_PRICE
PRODUCT_SKU
SALE_TIME

My question is which approach would generally be considered best practice when attempting to build a scalable efficient solution. Using foreign keys means data is not duplicated but the caveat is that database or application-level JOINS would be needed in order to query the entire dataset. However than being said, for some reason the foreign key approach seems cleaner and more correct somehow.

Comment: I believe what you are seeing is specific to the business case of e-commerce. At time of sale, the sales table is capturing relevant information to that specific sale. For instance, if you did not capture the sale price at time of sale, your sales history would change every time that the product table was updated with new product prices.

Comment: Yes I understand the SALES specific details being captured but my query is why are the the PRODUCT fields (i,e fields that are already defined in the product table PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME,etc) being defined again in the sales item table - These fields are unlikely to ever change?

Comment: *Unlikely* doesn't equal *never*. (Cynical--or highly experienced--sysadmins and DBAs will tell you that, when a client tells you something is unlikely to change, that means it will certainly change, and in fact it *probably* has *already* changed.) In relational terms, these values aren't duplicates, because they have different semantics. (They mean different things.) "Products.Product_name" means the current name of the product; "Sales_items.Product_name" means the name of the product at the time of this particular sale.

Comment: Also, when you stop selling the product if you have an FK in the sales table you can't delete it or your sales history is ruined. So you have to add a flag to the product saying whether or not is should be shown, which leads to complexity else where. Like all design decisions it's a trade off: dups here vs complexity there.